# JQuery ScrollTop glitches with fadeIn and fadeOut

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-animate

I'm getting this horrible glitch (it sort of jumps or flashes) when using animate scrolltop with fadeIn and fadeOut. I've got a Div which is dynamically loaded with content. When the user clicks a menu button on the main page the page should scroll to the top and then begin to fadeout the div, then update the div with it's new content and then fade back in.

It works fine half the time but the other half it glitches out. I tried firefox, chrome and opera and they all have the same behavior.

```
function loadPage(url)
{
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0}, 500);
    setTimeout(function (){ $('#centerBox').load(url); }, 1000);
    $('#centerBox').fadeOut(1000);
    $('#centerBox').fadeIn(1500);
}
```

Code Explanation:
So the above function will be called when a menu button is clicked. The main page will scroll to the top. The div's content has a timer so that's content is changed after the fadeout has fully completed but changed in enough time to be ready for the fadein.

I'm calling the loadPage(url) function using this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="loadPage('news.html');"><img src="buttons/newsWhite.png"/></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing it to this instead:

```
function loadPage(url)
{
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0}, 500, function(){
        $('#centerBox').fadeOut(1000, function(){
            $('#centerBox').load(url, function(){
                $('#centerBox').fadeIn(1500);
            }); 
        });   
    });
}
```

This will not load the url until the fadeOut animation is completed.

Comment: Thank you but I still get the weird glitchy behavior. So strange

Comment: @user1577433 ~ You could try putting the fadeIn in the complete function of the load call.

Comment: I've just updated the first post with how I'm calling the loadPage() function. Could this have anything to do with it?

Comment: @user1577433 ~ I don't think so. I think it has more to do with racing conditions. You want to start each step after the last one has completed. I'm going to update my answer with something else for you to try.

Comment: Still not working. I think it has something to do with the animate scrolltop because this glitch is happening when the page is slightly scrolled down and as soon as the a menu button is clicked which leads to the scrolling back up. Do you know of any other way to scroll to the top? Many thanks for your help by the way. Much appreciated!

Comment: Hey answered my own question

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have solved my issue here.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
        $('#news').click(function(){
            $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0}, 500, function(){
                $('#all').fadeOut(1000, function(){
                    $('#centerBox').load('news.html', function(){
                        $('#all').fadeIn(1500);
                    }); 
                });   
            }); 
            return false;
        });
     });
```

I then called this using:

```
 <a href="#" id="news");"><img src="buttons/newsWhite.png" width="130" height="25"/></a>
```

I'm new to JavaScript and JQuery (as you can probably tell), do you think it could have something to do with not using document.ready()?